# Two different behaviors when inserting HTML elements by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In my web application, I have a form that provides me to create new blog. The code is:

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="createBlog">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="BlogName">Blog Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Blog Name" name="blogName">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Content">Content</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="content" name="content"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Image">Upload Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myImage">
        </div>

        <button type="button" name="Add more image" class="btn btn-default" onclick="addMoreFile()">+ Add More Image</button>
        <br>
        <br>

        <button type="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">Send</button>

</form>
```

For this form, my plan is that when I press the "+ Add More Image" button, to create additional file upload area, which is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Image">Upload Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myImage">
</div>
```

To do this, I used Javascript and applied two approaches. When I used my first approach which is my prefer due to it is more easy to implement, nothing happened. For my second approach, it works.

**First Approach:**

```
function addMoreFile(){
    var createForm = document.getElementById("createBlog");
    var uploadFile = createForm.getElementsByTagName("div")[2];
    var firstButton = createForm.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
    createForm.insertBefore(uploadFile,createForm.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]);
}
```

**Second Approach:**

```
function addMoreFile(){
    var divNode = document.createElement("div");
    divNode.setAttribute("class","form-group");
    var labelNode = document.createElement("label");
    labelNode.setAttribute("for","Image");
    labelNode.innerHTML = "Upload Image";
    var myInput = document.createElement("input");
    myInput.setAttribute("type","file");
    myInput.setAttribute("class","form-control");
    myInput.setAttribute("name","myImage");
    divNode.appendChild(labelNode);
    divNode.appendChild(myInput);
    createForm.insertBefore(divNode,createForm.getElementsByTagName("button")[0]);
}
```

What is the difference between two approaches/codes, and why it is not work when I apply the first approach?

Comment: Well, as you have shown in your second approach, you *can* do what you want to do with plain JavaScript, but it would be so much easier if you used something like jQuery to help you. Using jQuery it would be a simple command like `$('#createBlog div.form-group:last').after(html_code_of_extra_form-group)`.

Comment: Your first approach does not create a new element.  I suspect it would work if you did, something like: `var uploadFile = createForm.getElementsByTagName("div")[2].cloneNode(true);`

Comment: @James I thought that "var uploadFile" is a copy of existing element like C programming language (pass by value). It is working when I did your solution.

Comment: Glad it's working.  Javascript only passes numbers and strings by value, everything else is by reference.